# How to edit the value of a variable in a TPL file

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to edit a TPL file from the OpenCart platform, I would put the "price" divided into 6 parts, but when I put `$pricecard = $ price / 6;` And `Echo $ pricecard;` No value is returned.

Here's my code

```
  <span> <?php echo "Ou em 6x de: " ?></span>
  <?php $a = 6; ?>
  <?php $pricecard = $price; ?>
  <span><?php $pricecard = $tbData->priceFormat($pricecard); ?></span>
  <span class="price-cartao"><?php echo $pricecard; ?></span>
```

I put `$pricecard` getting the value of `$price` and displayed normally, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually all the calculations and the variables **should** be inside the controller before the load of the view.

In your product.tpl the $price is already loaded as string because it has the currency symbol in it, so you cannot divide it by other variable.

I will attach a solution but by using the product controller.

So you open the file: catalog/controller/product/product.php and you search for line:

***For Opencart 1.5.x***

`$this->data['options'] = array();`

Before that line, you add:

`$a = 6;
$this->data['custom_price'] = $product_info['price'] / $a;`

***For Opencart 2.x***

`$data['options'] = array();`

Before that line, you add:

`$a = 6;
$data['custom_price'] = $product_info['price'] / $a;`

Of course you need to change the $a variable to whatever you want to have there.

Then you open the product.tpl file and you just show the information easily. 
For example:

`<span><?php echo $custom_price; ?></span>`

Hope I helped you. Cheers

Comment: Perfect! Worked perfectly. Thank you very much!